# Does Kubernetes Job/CronJob support diferent objects then Pods?

Tags: kubernetes, workflow

I want to know if I can manipulate different CRD's in my Job/CronJob in kubernetes. The documentation only show's a pod template, but I want to use different objects.

Comment: Entire Kubernetes turns around pods. Even the objects you want to create turn around pods. If not, it should be in a pod.

Comment: Hi @suren , I know that. But I want to start a workflow CRD inside my cron job. He will start a pod and complete a task. But the solution answered below was very clear. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Kubernetes does not support any other resource but pods, as these are the only resources that run containers in Kubernetes and Kubernetes, will need to spin up a Pod in order to run your task

If you want to setup a CronJob to use your CRD's then you might need to create your own CronJob spec, a very good example of this would be the [Kubebuilder tutorial](https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/cronjob-tutorial.html), they rebuild the whole CronJob

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly my doubt.